# Is Sora no Otoshimono Final: Eternal My Master the definite ending movie of the series?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

Is the new movie *Sora no Otoshimono Final: Eternal My Master* the definite ending movie of the series?

There are so many loopholes in the story which have yet to be filled in. And the series has been quite the success as well.

Comment: AFAIK, Sora no Otoshimono Final is the last movie of the series, if you want to know the whole story you can read the manga

Answer (score 3):

[『 そらのおとしものFinal 永遠の私の鳥籠 』](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sora_no_Otoshimono_Final:_Eternal_My_Master) (*Sora no Otoshimono Final: Eternal My Master*) was released as [劇場版第2作](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%89%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE#.E5.8A.87.E5.A0.B4.E7.89.88.E7.AC.AC2.E4.BD.9C) (second theatrical installment) following the first film 『劇場版 そらのおとしもの 時計じかけの哀女神』 (*Gekijouban Sora no Otoshimono Tokei jikake no Angeloid*).

When it was announced, [the announcement](http://kadokawa-anime.jp/soraoto/2013/10/2014.html) did not specify that this is absolutely the final film, but it did state:

> 『「第３期シリーズ」として発表しておりましたが、この度シリーズ作品ではなく...2014年に劇場公開することが大決定しました！！』
>
> "Although we had previously said there would be a third series [season], this time instead of a series...in 2014 it's been decided that there will be a theatrical release!"

A third season of the TV anime had previously [been promised](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%89%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE#.E3.83.86.E3.83.AC.E3.83.93.E3.82.A2.E3.83.8B.E3.83.A1) in the March 2012 issue of 「月刊少年エース」 (*Gekkan Shounen Ace*) magazine, but the film announcement corrects that to state that there will not be any further TV anime after all, and the second film is a replacement.

Whether there will ever be another film or OAV is not clearly articulated, but the title of the film implies that it is intended to be the final production. They could have used the term 完結編 (*kanketsuhen*, the last program of a series) in the title or in the announcement to explicitly state that there are no plans to ever produce a following work, but did not do so.

Answer (score 0):

The movie skipped too big or hopped way to far. They skipped those important scenes, like:

- Tomoki's world is not real (well, this part explains some point in the movie, but only a little.)
- Defeating the master of Synapse
- Mikako is a goddess?
- etc.

If you want to know more or fill the holes of the movie, I prefer you read the manga, which has the complete story (well, the anime comes from the manga).